# How do I hide Drupal nodes that shouldn't be directly accessed from users and search engines?

Tags: search, drupal-6, tabs, search-engine, drupal-views

I have seen many somewhat similar questions, but nothing quite what I'm looking for. So at the risk of being told this is a duplicate... here it goes.

I've found that there are times I have a node that simply contains content that will be displayed somewhere else, but shouldn't be viewed directly. That is, no one should ever go to node/1234, but the content in node 1234 should be displayed somewhere else.

For example, I create an about page with tabbed content using views. So there are "About Me", "About Us" and "About Them" pages. All of these are displayed in a single page with tabs using Views. So I don't want people to get directly to the "About Us" node because then they wouldn't see the tabs for the other pages. At the same time, I don't want Google giving people a direct link to this node, I want to limit access so users can only get to it through the View (i.e., the tab).

So I need to restrict access to the node, remove it from the Drupal search results, and make sure Google doesn't pick up on it. Any suggestions?

---- Note ----

I've accepted the answer from mingos (thanks btw) because even though it's not a full answer / solution, it gave me some good things to think about. Additional answers are still welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tough one.

If you want to have many nodes like this and do the "displaying elsewhere" dynamically, I can't think of anything right now (at 2:20 AM I rarely can).

If there is onne such page (or very few), I'd restrict access to it by any available means (Permissions, Nodeaccess, Content Access, TAC, whatever) and then create special themes for the pages where the restricted content should be displayed. The themes would contain database queries, fetching content from the restricted nodes.

Other possibility might include creating a special theme for the hidden nodes in question (perhaps all belonging to the same content type?). Make full node display nothing (or a message saying the access is restricted) and add a ROBOTS meta tag asking Google not to index the page. Make the teaser view available though - you can display it freely inside a view, but since /node/1234 is the FULL view, the actual content will be unavailable here.

Dunno if this solves your problem, hope it helps at least a bit.

Comment: Thanks mingos, it certainly is a tricky one. There aren't too many instances where I want to do this, so manual stuff is possible, but obviously creates maintenance nightmares. Unfortunately it might not be restricted to a single content type, or even all nodes of a given content type, which makes it even trickier.

Comment: Agree with the solutions @mingos has come up with. You can change your robots.txt file to exclude those URLs from search engines. Also you can make a special template file for those nodes which will show nothing when accessed.

Comment: Yes its definitely something to consider, though I'd love a more maintainable solution. This doesn't mention hiding it form the Drupal Search (which I realize I kinda left out of the question, will edit), but there seem to be some decent posts about that topic.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why would you do that anyway? Is there some reason behind hiding nodes, but displaying their content elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, I feel there are times I want to display content only in the context of other content. For example... a movie review. Yes, you could display it on it's own and link back to the movie. But say I want to display all the reviews in a tab on the Movie's page. If you show the full review there... why also display it on it's own page? It's mostly about controlling user experience and making sure they see things in the way I want them presented.

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 7 you can use: http://drupal.org/project/internal_nodes

Description: Some content/nodes should never be viewed directly; only visible be through something else such as Views or Panels. This module denies access to node/[nid] URLs while allowing the content to stay published and otherwise viewable.

Full disclosure: I am the creator and co-maintainer of Internal Nodes. I found this question while searching to see how the module could be found on Google.

Comment: This is a great solution to a very common problem - thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I found this page after running into this same problem.

What I found worked for me might be *part* of the answer you need:

Take a look at the Page Manager Redirect Module http://drupal.org/project/page_manager_redirect .  I just started playing with it.

It uses the Page Manager module of CTools to redirect one page to another.  What makes this most powerful is that Page Manager uses Contexts.  So, if you want to redirect all pages of a particular content type, you can do so.

I just started to use it (instead of Taxonomy Redirect and Path Redirect) to redirect (301 response code) my taxonomy terms for a particular vocabulary to particular nodes.

In your instance, you should be able to use contexts to filter for specific pages.

Of course this doesn't solve the problem of these nodes coming up in search results.

Comment: I think this is the best solution, even better now that the CTools Page Manager includes a HTTP Response Code Plugin. This screen cast shows the steps you need to take: http://nodeone.se/blogg/learn-page-manager-part-2-introduction-and-more

Answer (score 2):

There is also another module [Rabbit Hole](https://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) which has a similar functionality like [Internal Nodes](https://drupal.org/project/internal_nodes) but works for all entities, not only nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem, and are currently thinking of the following solution where all the content of a node is to be displayed to certain users (permission based):
- unpublish node
- create a new published checkbox
- create a view with fields that shows alle the content

Haven't tested it thoroughly yet, but it seems to work.

The node is to be displayed to the creator (only one in permission 1), some of it to permission 2 and all of it to permission 3.

Any comments on this solution.

I assume this will also exclude it from search, but permission 2 and 3 needs to be able to search it. Still haven't figured that one out.

Answer (score 0):

I used Rules module with an "entity is of bundle" and the built-in "Page redirect" action.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really easy way to do this if you only want to show a content type through a view.

1. create a content type as and make it unpublished.
2. create a view and on the filter option set the filter to "Content: Published (No)"

the view will give anon users access to the content through the view but they won't have access to the unpublished content at the direct link to the content.